# Jackson error converting object to List

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am trying to send an array of long value to my Spring controller.

```
     {
       "locationIds": [
                45,
                121,
                89
            ]
     }
```

In my controller, I have defined request body as

```
@RequestBody Object locationIds
```

I got an error while converting this object to list, code snippet is given below

```
List<Long> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, new TypeReference<Object>(){});
```

Error is

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring controller then why are you using Object mapper explicitly? MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from Spring framework can bind JSON payload to typed beans, or untyped HashMap instances. The error you are getting in `mapper.readValue` is giving you the hint. You can test it like below.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String js = "{\"locationIds\":[45,121,89]}";
Map<String,List<Long>> myObjects = mapper.readValue(js, new TypeReference<Object>(){});
List<Long> list = myObjects.get("locationIds");
```